# Can we deploy a Oracle Service Bus project in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat8, oracle-service-bus

Can we deploy a Oracle Service Bus project in tomcat? If yes then what changes do we need to do to the jar that we generate from OSB. Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. OSB can be deployed on Oracle WebLogic and maybe IBM WebSphere.